# Objective-c - iOS - hide/unhide label, textfield etc

Tags: objective-c, ios, label, hide

I want to hide/unhide controls of a subview in a view. For example: When a button action occurs, some labels will become hidden then unhide on a subsequent button action and so on. I have implemented this functionality through Interface Builder. How can I do the same implementation programmatically?

I've tried

```
[label1 hidden: true];
```

which hasn't worked for me.

Answer (score 57):

Here is the answer:

```
[label1 setHidden:YES];
```

`YES` is Objective-C's version of `true`.

Answer (score 12):

To hide a label:

```
self.yourlabelname.hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[self.view addsubview:self.label];`  to make the label visible.

Use `[self.label removefromSuperview];`  to remove from Superview.